# Component not rerendering after Redux state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a container with the following code:

```
class QuoteContainer extends Component {

  //FETCH ALL QUOTES
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchQuotes();
    this.props.fillColorArr();
  }

  checkIfQuotesReady = () => {
    let quotesCheck = this.props.quotesArr.length > 0;
    return quotesCheck;
  }

  changeQuoteHandler = () => {
    let randomQuote = this.props.quotesArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)];
    console.log(randomQuote);
    return randomQuote;
  }

  render() {

    let quotesReady = this.checkIfQuotesReady();

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        {quotesReady ? <Quote quote={this.changeQuoteHandler()}/> : null}
        <Button changeQuote={this.props.displayedQuotesCounter}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    quotesArr: state.quotes,
    counter: state.counter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchQuotes: () => {
      fetch('https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(quotes => dispatch({type: actions.FETCH_QUOTES, fillArr: quotes}))
    },
    fillColorArr: () => dispatch({type: actions.GET_COLORS}),
    displayedQuotesCounter: () => dispatch({type: actions.COUNT_QUOTES})
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuoteContainer);
```

"changeQuote" on the Button fires an action to update the already displayed quotes count (simple counter). As the counter changes in the Redux state I expected that the the Quote line:

```
{quotesReady ? <Quote quote={this.props.quotesArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}/> : null}
```

will rerender and hence a new random quote will be displayed on the screen.
It turns out that I'm wrong and I'm just curious what might be the possible solution for this one. Have in mind that the Quote component does not have access to the store but has been given the random quote which has been stored in it's local state.
Also here is my reducer:

```
import createColorArr from '../utils/colors';
import * as actions from './actions';

//CREATE COLORS ARRAY FROM OBJECT FILLED WITH COLORS
const colors = createColorArr(); //IS IT OK?

//INITIAL APPLICATION STATE
const initialState = {
  quotes: [],
  colors: [],
  shownQuotes: 1
}

//ROOT (AND THE ONLY ONE) REDUCER
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.FETCH_QUOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        quotes: state.quotes.concat(action.fillArr)
      };
    case actions.GET_COLORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        colors: state.colors.concat(colors)
      }
    case actions.COUNT_QUOTES:
      return{
        ...state,
        shownQuotes: state.shownQuotes + 1
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

export default reducer;
It is a learning purposes project, I am not looking for a solution where I will give an access to the store in the Quote component. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I will need to see your reducer code, rest of your component code, and what `checkIfQuotesReady` does.

Comment: Yes, sure. I edited my post and now it's all there.

Comment: Did you `connect` your component to redux?

Comment: Yes, sure. The counter is updating so I thought that the whole component should rerender.

Comment: I edited my post again and now also the export is there.

Comment: Can i see your reducer code too that has to do with both dispatched actions?

Comment: Sure, edited again.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understand is changeQuote on the button fires an action to update the already displayed quote counter but the updated count isn’t displayed. Am I right?

If so what you have to do is whenever you do update, you need to trigger fetch count action again to see updated count displayed otherwise it won’t. If you don’t do then You will only see the previous quote count but not the latest.

In changeQuote after update quote action call

```
     Do something like below for eg

     changeQuote = () => {
          this.props.updateCount();
          setTimeout(()=> {
                 this.props.getCount();
                 this.props.fetchCounts(); //whichever action fetches you the quote count
           }, 2000);
    }
```